# Why does fontspec interfere with metafont fonts?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, polyglossia

I need to create a document using a few fonts. Two or three will be `metafont` fonts used for most of the document in a Latin-based language, and then I need to use another font for a SE Asian language (so probably a TrueType font or similar as I can't find any TeX-based fonts that work with SE Asian languages). As I understand it, I can combine fonts quite easily for Latin-based languages:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Regular {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont and special} fonts.
\end{document}
```

gives me the desired effect:

[image]

but as soon as I add `fontspec`, which is required by `polyglossia`, the Zapf Chancery (`pzc`) font no longer works:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\thaifont{Norasi}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{thai}
\begin{document}
English regular {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont and special} fonts.\\
\begin{thai}ตัวพิมพ์ภาษาไทย\end{thai}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Is there any way to avoid this problem? To be clear, I *think* I must use `polyglossia` to use SE Asian languages, and I *must* use multiple `metafont` fonts as well.

### Answer

As pointed out by [Ulrike Fischer](/questions/166421#comment382315_166421), and further elucidated by [egreg](/a/166433/35260), `\fontencoding` needs to be specified when using metafont fonts under `fontspec` because the latter expects `EU1` whereas the former needs `T1` (I'm summarising from what I understand about `fontencoding`, which is not much).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\thaifont{Norasi}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{thai}
\begin{document}
English regular {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont and special} fonts.\\
\begin{thai}ตัวพิมพ์ภาษาไทย\end{thai}
\end{document}
```

yields the correct output:

[image]

Comment: You must change the encoding too:  {\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont and special}. Be careful with non-ascii-chars: some of them will not map to the correct glyph.

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer. `fontencoding` is indeed the issue as @egreg points out, `fontspec` expects `EU1`. Since you answered first, if you want to convert your comment to an answer, I'll mark yours as the answer. Otherwise, I'll give it to @egreg.

Comment: Note that you are  almost certainly *not* using metafonts at all. You are probably using type1 fonts.

Comment: @cfr `cmr` and `pzc` are not Type1, but _Norasi_ obviously is.

Comment: @yhten You are using `T1` so you are using type1 versions of the fonts unless you don't have them. I don't know if `pzc` is even available as metafont.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You often are able to find OpenType/TrueType substitutes for the fonts you need and this is the case with Zapf Chancery: a clone is available as TeX Gyre Chorus. But also native TeX/Metafont fonts can be used: an example with the Dürer font follows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\newfontfamily\thaifont{Sathu} % I don't have Norasi
\newfontfamily\specialfont{TeX Gyre Chorus}

\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{thai}

\usepackage{duerer} % for a MF font

\begin{document}

English regular {\specialfont and special} fonts.\\
\begin{thai}ตัวพิมพ์ภาษาไทย\end{thai}

\textdurm{ABCDE} % duerer has only uppercase

\end{document}
```

What `\textdurm{ABCDE}` does is, essentially,

```
{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{durm}\selectfont ABCDE}
```

and `\fontencoding{OT1}` (or `\fontencoding{T1}`) is what you were missing, because the default encoding with XeLaTeX and `fontspec` is `EU1`.

[image]